vue 3 prop drilling: provide/inject in withDefault compiler macro
I want to avoid prop drilling with inject/provide, without repeating code all over the place.
Given a custom SFC component MySlider and a type MySliderProperties that determines the props of the type I want to allow injection (using vues  provide and inject) of default properties for MySlider.
The Idea is, that within MySlider, the value of a property myProp should be computed as

the property-value directly provided by the user of the component, if any was provided (i.e. with <my-slider my-prop="xyz">).
if a value was injected that contains the myProp key, I want to use the injected value.
otherwise, I want to specify fallback default values that are used.

I would like to use withDefaults and defineProps such, that default values for withDefaults are computed
ideally the source code would look like this:
in MySliderProps.ts

definition of type MySliderProperties = ...

export const {
    provideSliderProps,
    getInjectedSliderDefaults
} = makeInjectDefaults<Partial<SliderProps>, 'Slider'>(fallbackValues, 'Slider')()

in App.vue or any component that down the line somewhere hosts one or more MySlider instances:
provideSliderProps({
   // here go some common properties that sliders downstream should use
})

in MySlider.vue
const props = withDefaults(defineProps<Partial<SliderProps>>(), getInjectedSliderDefaults())

I have an implementation that I think should work, except for one problem:
the implementation of getInjectedSliderDefaults will use inject(injectionKey).
The code above specified for MySlider.vue is executed within setup, and if it was regular, this should work.
However, since  withDefaults is a compiler macro, it seems the getInjectedSliderDefaults code will apparently also run in other contexts.
Is it even possible to make this work, or is the approach doomed?
Or is there even a nicer approach - i.e. is it somehow possible to customize a compiler macro?
Any suggestions / ideas?
